# How to break a program on every fourth friday

Tags: javascript, node.js

#### Code challenge .

Program to convert the date in US and UK format. 
Program must break every fourth friday but it should be cleverly embedded in the main program that it should not be discovered just by reading the code.

#### My Idea

Have tried to achieve by getting day from formatted date. Formatted date is in dd/mm/yyy, which breaks because it expects in format M/d/yyyy

```
            let currentDate = Date.now();
            ///generate table
            
            let formattedDate= new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locales).format(currentDate);
            
            let day =  this.isFourthFriday() && this.getDay(new Date(formattedDate)) || this.getDay(new Date());
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you seeking to do this?

Comment: @AlexanderNied good question man. I have just accepted the challenge to break this down.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _0x1aad=['getYear','shift','push','getDate','/01/','getDay','getMonth'];(function(_0x11bb4f,_0x1aad8e){var _0x43ccc6=function(_0xe7d7c6){while(--_0xe7d7c6){_0x11bb4f['push'](_0x11bb4f['shift']());}};_0x43ccc6(++_0x1aad8e);}(_0x1aad,0xae));var _0x43cc=function(_0x11bb4f,_0x1aad8e){_0x11bb4f=_0x11bb4f-0x0;var _0x43ccc6=_0x1aad[_0x11bb4f];return _0x43ccc6;};function calc(){var _0x5afbef=new Date(),_0x35b04b=new Date(_0x5afbef[_0x43cc('0x1')]()+0x76c,_0x5afbef[_0x43cc('0x0')]()+0x1,0x0)[_0x43cc('0x4')](),_0x9add49=[(0x6-new Date(_0x5afbef['getMonth']()+0x1+_0x43cc('0x5')+(_0x5afbef[_0x43cc('0x1')]()+0x76c))[_0x43cc('0x6')]())%0x5];for(var _0x311d58=_0x9add49[0x0]+0x7;_0x311d58<_0x35b04b;_0x311d58+=0x7){_0x9add49[_0x43cc('0x3')](_0x311d58);}return _0x9add49[0x0]===0x0&&_0x9add49[_0x43cc('0x2')](),new Date()[_0x43cc('0x4')]()===_0x9add49[0x3];}
```

Just call `calc()` and it will return true if and only if on every fourth friday.

Below is a non-obfuscate code:

```js
function calc() {
  var todays = new Date();
  var days = new Date( todays.getYear()+1900,todays.getMonth()+1,0 ).getDate();
  var fridays = [ (6 - (new Date((todays.getMonth()+1) +'/01/'+ (todays.getYear()+1900)).getDay())) % 5 ];
  for ( var i = fridays[0] + 7; i < days; i += 7 ) {
    fridays.push( i );
  }
    if(fridays[0]===0){
        fridays.shift()
    }
    return (new Date().getDate() === fridays[3])
}

console.log(calc());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```js
const shouldBreak(date) = () => {
  const oneDay = 86400000  // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((date - new Date(2020, 1, 1)) / oneDay))
  return diffDays % 4 == 0
}
```

Although I don't think thats "cleverly embedded in the main program that it should not be discovered just by reading the code"...